# Exponent Laws [confused?]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just reading about exponent laws and came across the image below.

On the first line, if I solve the equation commutativity, I get the answer $a^5$, but if I solve it with the distributive method I get $6a^2$. Why am I getting two different answers for equally valid methods?

[image]

Comment: How are you using distributivity?

Comment: It is not possible: in the multiplication $a$ occurs five times. Thus, it must be $a^5$

Answer (score 3):

I must tell you that what you are doing is not correct as $(a*a)(a*a*a)$ and $(a+a)(a+a+a)$ are **not** the same thing.
In the first case the two $a$ are multiplied but in the second case, the $a$ has been added.
If we need to use the distributive property, then the $a$ must be added not being multiplied, so that is were you went wrong.

$$(a*a)(a*a*a)=a^5$$
$$(a+a)(a+a+a)=6a^2$$
Hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

[Distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) is about two operations. For example, $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b + a\cdot c.$ You cannot apply it to $a\cdot (b\cdot c).$

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with numbers? What makes you do
$$
32=2^2\times2^3\stackrel?=6\times2^2=24?
$$